# What is the Regex for this case

Tags: regex, json

I want to get the "SuperHouse" value from "House" expression from a JSON return. 
I tried `"House":"(.+?)"` but it didnt work.

```
    {
    type: "Benefits"
    members: [1]
    0:  {
    type: "Benefits2"
    House: {
    color: "red"
    name: "SuperHouse"
    Category: "big hoses"
           }
        }
   }
```

What would be the Regex?

Comment: What **language** are you using? Use a proper parser.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. `members` appears to be an array because of the `[ ]`, but an array does not have key:value pairs, only a simple list of values. Start with valid JSON and then someone may have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
"House" : "?([^,]*)"?
```

But then again using a parser would make things a lot easier

**Edit**: Parsing a generic json fragment is not possible using just regexp. This is because regexp are equivalent with [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) but you need something "stronger" to math an arbitrary number of opened/closed symbols, something more like a [push down automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

Comment: Im going to use this just once. So for a generic purpose, I feel that an additional  Library is not needed. I have changed the Json a little bit, as I thought that your solution would work for every House, but as soon as I changed the Json for a more realistic, your expression didnt work anymore.

Comment: OK. Now I understand what you want and the answer is that you cannot do that. If the structure of House is an arbitrary json object then you cannot parse that using reg exp, because you'll need to be able to count the number of opened/closed brackets and the number of opened/closed curly brackets. This is simply impossible with reg exp.

Answer (score 0):

`"House":"(.+?)"` doesn't work because the value of the `House` property is not surrounded by quotes and there is also a space between the value and the `:`. These are all things you have to consider when constructing a regex to get values out of JSON properties.

If your JSON looks like that and all you need to do is get this specific value this one time, you can use `"House": (.*)`.

You should be using a JSON parser for whatever platform you are working with. Many languages/platforms have built-in JSON parsers including JavaScript and PHP. Others like Java have popular libraries like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

If you need to do this in bash/command line, I recommend [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk)